# scroll to Div after OnClick event (c#)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i do have a linkbutton that do some codebehind on c#.

and i want that, after the codebehind is done, and the result comes back to the page, the scroll moves to a certain div.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" OnClick="lb1_Click"> Click Aqui </asp:LinkButton>


<div id=myDiv> Hi! </div>

</body>
</html>
```

code behind:

```
protected void lb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something in database
   // then back to the page, and scroll to MyDiv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you, just change in the javascript the file that have the code and it will output the things in the file called

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function lb1_Clicks() {
   $.ajax({
    url: "getInfo.php",//set the file that will do the magic output
    success: function(response) {
     $('.myDiv').html(response).fadeIn();
    }
   });

}
  
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" OnClick="lb1_Click()"> Click Aqui </asp:LinkButton>


<div class="myDiv"><!-- your code will update here || example hello World--></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- getInfo.php -->
<?PHP
echo "hello world";
?>
```